# .htaccess redirect from image to article

Tags: image, .htaccess, redirect, hotlinking

im trying to redirect traffic i get from reddit to an article, but the image in the article is being hot-linked on reddit.com

this is fine but im wondering if theres a way that when users click on the image on reddit.com with a path like:

`http://mysite.com/i/12345.jpg` to redirect to `http://mysite.com/r/12345`

the only site I've noticed to do this successfully is livememe.com which has an image on reddit redirect to the article when clicked on. for example:

`http://www.livememe.com/36opcf5.jpg` redirects to `http://www.livememe.com/36opcf5`

and im trying to do something similar. Ive noticed that this redirect occurs whenever you go directly to that url.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^i/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.(jpe?g|JPE?G)$ /r/$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: would this work for alphanumeric characters as well? like mysite.com/i/12ab3c.jpg

Comment: this works, but a bit to well as i implement some of these images in my site and this renders the images broken

Comment: Maybe it is because of your picture format. I edited my code.

Comment: Ok. And do you have punctuation characters in the name of your images ?

Comment: ah that broke the entire page

Comment: It's strange. The NC flag doesn't care whether letters appear as upper-case or lower-case in the matched URI. So I don't understand why my code doesn't work.

Comment: weird fwiw my images are saved in JPG format as jpg wouldnt load them, i would need JPG to be upercased.

Comment: should i be implementing the images in the page differently from the <img src=""> code?

Comment: page loads now but img still fails to load

Comment: As you want, you can put this link mysite.com/i/6b5a4.jpg or this link mysite.com/r/6b5a4

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a few months since you asked, but if you still need a solution, I found an answer. Tried to find how it is done for a few hours, but unsuccessfully, so I had to come up with my own solution. Livememe doesn't do that redirect with htaccess, they do it with PHP. Since you can't see the difference in referrer, it would be the same whether the picture is embedded, or user clicks a link to it, you have to check something else. And the only difference I see is HTTP_ACCEPT header. If a resource is used as an image, it won't send HTTP_ACCEPT  with a value of "text/html", it will be "image/jpeg" or something like that. So what you do is something like this: first, create .htaccess file with this:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /redirect.php?q=$1 [L]
```

So if a file is not found, redrect.php is loaded (wile your URL stays the same). And inside redirect.php put something like this:

```
$accept = explode(',', $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']);

$file = $_GET['q'];
$file_info = pathinfo( $file );
$url = $file_info['filename'];
$ext = $file_info['extension'];
$check_html = array_search('text/html', $accept);

if ( file_exists("$url.html") ) {
    if ($check_html !== FALSE) header("location: http://yourdmain.com/$url"); // location of URL you want to redirect to
    else header("location: http://i.yourdomain.com/$url.$ext"); // loction of image file
}
else {
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    print 'File not found';
}
```

Adjust according to your server (the file_exists() part). Or you can check the database, to see that such post exists. Well, I think you get the idea, how that is done. Hope that helps.